# How does typescript decide which JSX.IntrinsicElements defintion to use when multiple exist?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am building a ReactJS app in typescript. I'm getting a compiler error in a particular TSX file because it thinks that the type of my onMouseDown handler is incorrect:

```
Type '(event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void'
```

From my investigation, it looks like the issue is due to a mismatch of react versions. It appears that the type of this MouseEvent handler changed in a newer react version.

My app has a dependency on react as well as the @types/react, of course.  However, my app also has a dependency on another package that we'll call 'foo.' If I look in the 'foo' directory in my node_modules directory, 'foo' also has its own node_modules directory with a @types/react under it -- one that is older than the one my app depends on directly.

When I try to return a  element from a function my TSX file, it appears to be using the definition for  from the *older* JSX.IntrinsicElements interface that is under the node_modules directory under foo. However, it looks like the definition for ReactElement (the type my function is returning) is coming from the *newer* JSX.IntrinsicElements. As such, there is a clash because the older  type does not match the definition of the newer ReactElement type (specifically the MouseEvent).

I further validated my theory by changing my function to instead return the div by using React.createElement("div"...) and that silenced the error, since the use of "React" there explicitly refers to the React package that my tsx file imported at the top -- thus sidestepping any automatic lookup of types from JSX.InstrincicElements.

So my question is -- how does typescript (and VS Code) decide which JSX.IntrinsicElements definition to use when there are multiple in existence? And is there any way to get it to use the one that is from the react package that is explicitly listed as a dependency of my project, rather than one that just happens to be under a different module that coincidentally also uses the react types?

Thanks!